# How to do non-greedy match in expr

Tags: regex

I'm using bash. I've tried everything I could. It always works in regexr. It works for other files. For one file, it simply does not work, no matter what. I can't use `?` make a quantifier lazy. I can't isolate the dbsnp file. Please help me!

```
vcfs=$(find . -type f -name "*\.vcf" -printf "%f\n")

echo "$vcfs"

>1000G_omni2.5.b37.vcf

>1000G_phase1.indels.b37.vcf

>1000G_phase1.snps.high_confidence.b37.vcf

>dbsnp_138.b37.vcf

>hapmap_3.3.b37.vcf

>Mills_and_1000G_gold_standard.indels.b37.vcf

thousandG=`expr "$vcfs" : '.*\(1000G_phase1.indels[^\n]*\.vcf\)'`

echo $thousand

>1000G_phase1.indels.b37.vcf

GoldStandard=`expr "$vcfs" : '.*\(Mills_and_1000G_gold_standard.indels[^\n]*\.vcf\)'`

echo $GoldStandard

>Mills_and_1000G_gold_standard.indels.b37.vcf

dbsnp=`expr "$vcfs" : '.*\(dbsnp_[1-9][3-9][3-9][^\n]*\.vcf\)'`

echo $dbsnp

>dbsnp_138.b37.vcf

>hapmap_3.3.b37.vcf

dbsnp=`expr "$vcfs" : '.*\(dbsnp_[1-9][3-9][3-9][^\n]*?\.vcf\)'`

echo $dbsnp

>

dbsnp=`expr "$vcfs" : '.*\(dbsnp_[1-9][3-9][3-9].*?\.vcf\)'`

echo $dbsnp

>

echo `expr "$vcfs" : '.*\(hapmap_[\n]*\.vcf\)'`

>hapmap_3.3.b37.vcf
```

Comment: I run your `dbsnp=\`expr "$vcfs" : '.*\(dbsnp_[1-9][3-9][3-9][^\n]*\.vcf\)'\`` on my redhat machine, and the output is `dbsnp_138.b37.vcf`, which is right! So what os are you using?

Comment: I think I'm using CentOS, but I'm not sure. The specs just say Linux.

Comment: `cat /etc/centos-release`

Comment: turns out it's redhat: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)

Answer (score 1):

From man page of `expr` :

> STRING : REGEX
>        Perform pattern matching.  The arguments are coerced to strings
>        and the second is considered to be a **(basic, a la GNU `grep')**
>        regular expression

In basic GNU grep regex, non-greedy match modifier is not supported.

Consider using other tools like `sed`, `awk`, `grep -P` etc

---

In your specific example (there will not be newlines in filenames), you can simply do `echo "$vcfs" |grep "^dbsnp_[1-9][3-9][3-9].*\.vcf"`

Comment: I tried the \r option initially. It didn't work. I will try the grep though. Did my previous comment disappear?

Comment: dunno about your "previous comment".  I will just remove the `\r` solution as I don't think it applies universally.  Btw, may the downvoter please tell why downvote?